# onScroll attribute not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Even it is not console.log **0**

my code:

```
//...existing code
handleScroll=(event)=>{
        console.log(0)
        const bottom = event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight;
        if(bottom){
            console.log('bottom')
        }
    }
//...code

<div onScroll={this.handleScroll}>{s}</div>

//...code
```

is there any problem?

Comment: Should be OK, do you really scroll the div, that has the onScroll listener? Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: @Fide, sir, my div has no onScroll listener. How do i add the listener?

Comment: With onScroll property you add the listener, the question is, if it really is scrolling, isn't it only wrapper for someelement which is trully scrolling? Or isn't scrolling parent element? Try to add simple logging onScroll property to parent and child elements, maybe you find out more.